# getElementByID on first mount is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pull "activity_type" with `getElementById()` on mount, but it is returning nothing (which is default state value). I am doing this in my `componentDidMount()`.

I tried creating a defaultValue but that didnt fix it either. This is a modal and if I close it and open it again it works as expected.

```
componentDidMount () {
   const {handleModalMount}= this.props
   handleModalMount(document.getElementById("activity"))
}

render(){
   ....
   return(
   ...
   <select style={{fontWeight:'900', fontSize:'12px'}} className="no-radius" id="activity" name="selectedActivity" onChange={(e)=> handleClick(e)}> 
  {(activity_options.filter(option => selectedType === option.activityRefName)).map((activity, i) => 
   {return (
      <option key={i} value={activity.activityTypeName}>{activity.activityTypeName}</option>
)
   })}
   </select>
)}
```

Comment: consider using a `ref` for this , rather than using `getElementById()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more reliable way to aquire a DOM element in your component is via a `ref`. There are a few ways this can be achieved - one is via a callback on the `<select/>` element like so:

```
ref={ element => this.handleModalMount(element) }
```

You should find that the following adjustment to your component's `render()` method (and `componentDidMount()` method) will achieve what you require:

```
componentDidMount () {
    // No need for this
    // const {handleModalMount}= this.props
    // handleModalMount(document.getElementById("activity"))
  }

  render(){
    ....
    return(
    ...
    <select ref={ element => this.handleModalMount(element) } 
            style={{fontWeight:'900', fontSize:'12px'}} 
            className="no-radius" id="activity"
            name="selectedActivity" 
            onChange={(e)=> handleClick(e)}> 
        {(activity_options
          .filter(option => selectedType === option.activityRefName))
          .map((activity, i) => { return (
          <option key={i} 
                  value={activity.activityTypeName}>
                  {activity.activityTypeName}
          </option>)})}
    </select>)}
```

See these links for more information on the [concept of refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), and more specifically [call back refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

Comment: When I hit my `handleModalMount` it shows the expected reference, but somehow null is being passed as an element. Thanks for the explanation too in the answer and code formatting

Comment: nvm, the handleModalMount was passed as a prop and I brought it into the child component (the code I posted) and this fixed.

Comment: hi @user10204157 , glad I could help - all the best with your project :)